# twitter oauth does not work on air ios, but works on air android

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, air, twitter-oauth

I have air application that runs over android and ios. I used the following library for twitter api.
https://github.com/ShanghaiTimes/tweetr-api1.1-AS3
Strange enough I have it working perfect on android version, but I get Http status 401 on ios when I make /oauth/request_token call, for the same user logged in and the same twitter application.
For debugging, I made some modifications for how this /oauth/request_token request is built, and I always get it working on ios, but not android.

Thank you for advance.

Comment: I am not getting Profile Image on Win7 and Air2.0

Comment: it is pretty annoying, I even tried another library to get it working on android but not on ios.https://github.com/susisu/Twitter-for-AS3

Comment: Can you please send which another library used?

Comment: @RajneeshGaikwad sorry the link was not clear in the previous comment. it is called twitter-for-as3. https://github.com/susisu/Twitter-for-AS3